# How to fix Fastlane supply missing_email

Tags: continuous-integration, google-oauth, fastlane

Fastlane ends up giving me this error:

```
/root/.rubygems/gems/googleauth-0.6.6/lib/googleauth/json_key_reader.rb:39:in `read_json_key': [!] missing client_email (RuntimeError)
```

Here's my `google-services.json`:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": <number>,
    "firebase_url": <firebase_url>,
    "project_id": <project_id>,
    "storage_bucket": <storage_bucket>
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": <mob_app_id>,
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": <package_name>
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": <client_id>,
          "client_type": <client_type>
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": <current_key>
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

I tried to search for where the `client_email` key would sit but I couldn't info on the format of this son file. Or at least what I found did not match the format I have at all.

Questions:

1) Where must I insert the `client_email` in the JSON to get it working?

2) Does the email have to match something in the Google Play account?

Comment: I wonder if I'm using the wrong JSON file. Seems like what I need is a file that's called `client_secret.json` by default, and it's generated after adding a services account on Google Play. The thing is though, `json_key_file` in `Fastlane/Appfile` currently points to the `google-services.json` file given in my question. I don't know why this was done...

Comment: i have the same issue. any solution?

Comment: @RajeshNasit Trying to remember how I fixed it. I think what I’ve suggested in my previous comment is what I ended up doing and it worked: i.e, add a service account, grab the json file that’s generated and point json_key_file to it.

Comment: got it let me try. thanks. i was doing same mistake like you.

Comment: Now i am getting  The request could not be completed because:Unauthorized Access

Comment: can you tell me why i am getting this?

Comment: @RajeshNasit Hmm, sounds like could be a permission issue. Make sure the service account created has the `Release Manager` Role granted to it as per the instructions at: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/supply/#setup

Comment: i have fixed thanks problem is service account not properly granted